# SQLite replace() specified character and next character

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with a `Username` column.

There are multiple section signs followed by numbers `§#` that format the name.

I have to make sure all names are unique, but I want to disregard the formatting character pairs.

I was going to use,

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE replace(lower(Username),'§%','') = 'name';`

but I realized that would look for the percent sign and not act as a wildcard. I could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` to isolate the name before comparing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(Username, 1, INSTR(Username, '§%') - 1)) = 'name';
```

Comment: I should've specified, the names can contain many of these format codes throughout.